# Pause or run in real time setInterval function while in inactive tab

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, settimeout, setinterval

Ive created this function that pulses a button every 3 seconds. Now, on the website Im working on, there are like 16 of them on the page at the same time all going off half a second apart from eachother. Now when the tab becomes inactive, the timings get all screwed up and it doesnt work. What can I add to the code to make it so that it either pauses the animations or has them keep going in real time when the tab is inactive. I personally do not care which one works, as long as it works.

I have made a fiddle for this project.

http://jsfiddle.net/JuFxn/

The code for the pulse is this

```
function fadeItIn() {

  window.setInterval(function () {

    // Fade Ins
    $('#child4').fadeIn(175);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#child3').fadeIn(175);
    }, 175);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#child2').fadeIn(175);
    }, 350);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#child1').fadeIn(175);
    }, 525);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#child').fadeIn(175);
    }, 700);

    // Fade Outs
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#child').fadeOut(175);
    }, 875);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#child1').fadeOut(175);
    }, 1050);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#child2').fadeOut(175);
    }, 1225);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#child3').fadeOut(175);
    }, 1400);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#child4').fadeOut(175);
    }, 1575);

  }, 3000);
}
```

The function is called at the beginning of the JS document. Again I do not mind which one works, as long as it works.

Comment: FWIW, even when the page isn't inactive, those timings will slowly drift. The value you give to `setTimeout` isn't absolutely precise. I'd use a single 125ms timer instead, and remember which element to fade (and in which way). But that doesn't address your...wait a minute, maybe it does. I'll post an answer. :-)

Comment: I love that last part haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even when the page isn't inactive, those timings will slowly drift. The value you give to `setTimeout` isn't absolutely precise.

Because of that, and because I think it will address your actual question as well, I'd recommend using a single 125ms timer instead, and remembering what child to fade (and in which way). That way, if that one timer is suspended, it picks up where it left off (and you don't have the issue of drift).

Something like this: [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JuFxn/2/)

```
$('.child0,.child1,.child2,.child3,.child4').hide();
fadeItIn();

function fadeItIn() {
    var child;

    child = 4;
    setTimeout(fadeIn, 3000);

    function fadeIn() {
        $("#child" + child).fadeIn(175);
        --child;
        if (child >= 0) {
            // Continue fading in
            setTimeout(fadeIn, 175);
        }
        else {
            // Start fading out
            ++child;
            setTimeout(fadeOut, 175);
        }
    }

    function fadeOut() {
        $("#child" + child).fadeOut(175);
        ++child;
        if (child <= 4) {
            // Continue fading out
            setTimeout(fadeOut, 175);
        }
        else {
            // Start over again
            setTimeout(fadeIn, 3000 - 1575);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: I changed your `child` to `child0`. It's best to be consistent with these things. :-)

(Also, there's no need for a semicolon after your `fadeItIn` function declaration. Declarations don't have semicolons after them; expressions do. It's harmless, but I thought I'd mention it.)

Comment: Hey T.J. Thanks for the answer. I have only been working with jQuery for like a week and am still unfamiliar with the terminology and syntax. Is there any chance you can help me out with coding that? Thanks :)

Comment: @YeahMKD: I appear to have been doing that while you were commenting. :-)

Comment: Oh wow thank you so much :D wow I have no idea how this thing works haha. Best start discecting it I suppose. Thank you so much :D

Comment: You know, I just looked at it right now, and it still acts the same way as it was before. The order of the pulses still shifts when going to another tab.

Comment: @YeahMKD: Yeah, there were still two timers, weren't there? The `setInterval` one, and the `setTimeout` one, so there was still interplay. See the update, now we **really** only have one timer.

Comment: Oh wow. It works YAY :D I think I understand whats going on sort of. I will have to dissect it a lot more. Thanks for all the help :D

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35845/discussion-between-yeahmkd-and-t-j-crowder)

Comment: I do have one last question. When you type  $("#child" + child).fadeIn(175); does the "#child" mean anything with child in the id?

Comment: @YeahMKD: Yes. If the variable `child` contains `4`, then the expression `"#child" + child` results in the string `"#child4"`, which is then passed into `$()` as a selector.

Comment: I added a second pulse and duplicated the function and added the word "doom" at the end of each element and changed all "child" to "doom". Why wont both of them execute when the page loads?

Here is the updated fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/JuFxn/5/

Comment: @YeahMKD: Using any modern browser, open the developer tools (it'll be on the menus somewhere, or F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I are both popular keyboard shortcuts for it) and look at the "Console". That'll tell you what's going wrong. (You've used `fadeInDoom` where you meant `fadeIn`.)

Comment: But since the fadeIn is already using "#child", doesnt there need to be a seperate function to run through elements that have a different ID? I have to run this code on 16 different pulses throughout the project Im doing.

Comment: I think I got it to work. http://jsfiddle.net/JuFxn/6/ What do you think? Is there any way to make fadeItInDoom to start running 500ms after FadeItIn runs without using a setTimeout?

Comment: @YeahMKD: You didn't have to change all the function names. The problem was that in one place, you were trying to call `fadeInDoom` on a jQuery object, which doesn't have a method called `fadeInDoom`. It was just a typo. All you had to do was change that one call to `fadeIn` instead; **your** function can be called `fadeInDoom` if you like.

Comment: Oh I didnt catch that the fadeIn there was the actual jQuery fadeIn method. I though you were calling the function for some reason haha. Opps :P Now is there any way I can make the second pulse start after the first one without using a setTimeout method? I dont want the timings to mess up because of those. I could imagine I could use a Queue.

Comment: @YeahMKD: We're very, very far afield of the original question. Have a go at figuring it out, and if you can't (and I think based on your original code that you can), post a new question showing what you've tried and someone will help you with it.

Comment: Ok that sounds great. Again thanks so much for helping me out :D